# Generic wildcard invocation won't compile

Tags: java, generics

I am currently working with Generics and I'm not that experienced. I got this problem:

I made this class to compare 2 values implementing `Comparable` and do some other stuff, let's say incrementing the `compareTo()` value:

```
public final class Type<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    public int compare(T val1, T val2) {
        int compTemp = val1.compareTo(val2);
        compTemp++;
        // do stuff
        return compTemp;
    }
}
```

Now I create some instances of `Type`:

```
Type<Integer> t1 = new Type<Integer>();
Type<String> t2 = new Type<String>();
```

And now I want to put them into a `Map.` As I cannot predict the generic type of `Type` I use the wilcard `?`:

```
Map<String, Type<?>> map = Maps.newHashMap();

map.put("t1", t1);
map.put("t2", t2);
```

If I want to invocate `Type.compare()` it's working for `t1`, but not for `map.get(t1)`:

```
t1.compare(1,1); // compiles fine
map.get("t1").compare(1, 1); // does not compile
```

The latter throws a compilation error:

> The method compare(capture#3-of ?, capture#3-of ?) in the type
>   Type is not applicable for the arguments (int, int)

I know it's because of my wildcard parameter, but I don't exactly know why and how to fix this.
The only "fix" I see is to use raw types for the Map, however this will show several warnings.
I suppose right now I have a huge misunderstanding of the wilcard parameter.

I appreciate every answer!

Comment: `.get(t1)`? Your keys to the map are `String`s; your `t1` is not a string.

Comment: typo, but doesn't change the fact, that it does not work

Comment: The wildcard means that you don't care about the actual type it represents. But clearly you do care, that's where the problem lies. Think about what would happen if you passed that map to me and I sneakily did a `map.put("t1", new Type<String>());`? How could the compiler detect that?

Comment: Have u tried instanceof keyword determine which kind of data actually hashmap have `map.get("t1") instanceof classname` then typecast and put `compare()` method. Hope you will get your answer

Comment: Actually I want to insert Type<String>, Type<Long>, whatever is Comparable. But I think I got the reason it won't work. If Type could be of type anything how could I dynamically pass Objects of the right generic type. Any solutions for doing so other than limited casts?

Comment: Another question: the implementation of `compare()` seems to be always the same. So why would you need different instances anyways?

Comment: I wanted to ensure that e.g. only Integers could be passed to `compare()` if `Type<Integer>`. This rule has no effect it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a the `wildcard <?>` in your Map means your Map does not know the exact type. For the Map they are all stored as `Type<Object>`.
One thing you can do here is some type unsafe casting

```
((Type<Integer>)map.get("t1")).compare(1, 1); // does compile but is type unsafe
```

Another solution would be to store the generic Class when creating your `Type` Objects in constructor. Then you can do some type safe casting in your `compare` method using another method generic Type. See this `Type` class

```
public final class Type<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    Class<T> type;
    Type(Class<T> _type){
        type = _type;
    }

    public <E extends Comparable<E>> int compare(E val1, E val2) {
        T v1 = type.cast(val1);
        T v2 = type.cast(val2);

        int compTemp = v1.compareTo(v2);
        compTemp++;
        // do stuff
        return compTemp;
    }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
    Type<Integer> t1 = new Type<Integer>(Integer.class);
    Type<String> t2 = new Type<String>(String.class);

    Map<String, Type<?>> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put("t1", t1);
    map.put("t2", t2);

    map.get("t1").compare(1, 1); // compiles fine
    map.get("t2").compare("one", "one"); // compiles fine
```

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want, as I may iterate my Map and don't know the generic type.

Comment: Give a try   ((Type) map.get("t1")).compare(1, 1)  that will be compile but not type safety

Comment: @Don if you don't know the type at compile time then how would you supply parameters, i.e. how would you know the type of the parameters? Consider you called `map.get("t2").compare(1,1)` which should not work.

Comment: This seems to be pretty good. Is there a way to avoid the constructor parameter as the type is already known by the generic?

Comment: The `<E>` is superfluous in your example. Might as well accept `Object`.

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is no. Due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) your generic type is lost at runtime, so it need to be set somewhere manually.

Comment: @Radiodef I prefer the version with `<E>` as it provides better visibility in code.

Comment: @Don It doesn't do anything. ;)

Comment: @Radiodef Well, the compiler is a bit more kind as it says `(Integer, Integer)` instead of `(Object, Object)` and I can, as edited above, use `<E extends Comparable<E>>` to allow same types only for `compare()`.

Comment: @Don The compiler knows what you're passing regardless. The edit is an improvement.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to do something like this at runtime:

```
String key = getKeyFromParams(p1, p2);
map.get( key ).compare(p1, p2);
```

Since the compiler doesn't know the generic type of the value it returns for the key you can't just call compare() that way.

You could, however, restructure your code a bit to make it work (still with warnings and the need to take care not to break anything):

1. Make your compare() method accept `Comparable` parameters
2. Pass the class of the generic type to the constructor and use it to check the parameters in compare()

   - if the parameter types are ok compare them
   - if they don't match the type class throw an exception
3. use the type class as the map key and use it for the lookup

Example:

```
public final class Type<T extends Comparable<T>> {
  private final Class<T> typeClass;

  public Type( Class<T> typeClass) { 
    this.typeClass = typeClass;
  }

  public int compare(Comparable val1, Comparable val2) {
    if( !(typeClass.isInstance( val1 ) && typeClass.isInstance( val2 ) ) ) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("message");
    } 

    int compTemp = val1.compareTo(val2);
    compTemp++;
    // do stuff
    return compTemp;
  }

  //getter for the typeClass
}
```

A wrapper for the map:

```
class TypeComparator { 
  Map<Class<?>, Type<?>> map = new HashMap<Class<?>, Test.Type<?>>();

  public void addType(Type<?> type) {
    map.put( type.getTypeClass(), type );
  }

  public <T extends Comparable<T>> void compare(T p1, T p2) {
    map.get( p1.getClass() ).compare( p1, p2 );
  }
}
```

And finally call it like this:

```
//add some types
TypeComparator comp = new TypeComparator();
comp.addType( new Type<Integer>( Integer.class ));
comp.addType( new Type<String>( String.class ));

//compare ints    
comp.compare( 1, 1 );

//compare Strings
comp.compare( "1", "1" );

//won't compile
comp.compare( "1", 1 );
```

Some final thoughts:

- You have to handle cases where there is no type in the map (e.g. if one passed `Double` parameters in the example)
- You'll still get warnings but if you hide them well in the implementation and take care not to apply casts on the wrong types you should be fine.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, however it's the same as ArcticLord's if I don't miss something.

Comment: @Don yes it's basically the same. Unfortunately there aren't that many options here. If you elaborate a bit on what you're eventually trying to do there might be a better solution.

Comment: I definitively have to do some redesign. But you guys gave me a good solution and revealing my design error.